# How can I use a variable inside a for loop?

Tags: c#

```cs
using System;

namespace something
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int roomHeight = 10;
            int roomLength = 10;
            string Length;

            for (int i=0; i < roomLength; i++)
            {
                Length = string.Join(Length, ("a"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile, it does not recognize `Length = string.Join(Length, ("a"));`

I want it to recognize it as the string I declarated.

Comment: assign Lenght before using it like `string Lenght = string.Empty`

Comment: You need to initialize `Length`. You can change `string Length` to e.g. `string Length=""`.

Comment: `Lenght = string.Join(Lenght, ("a"));` <-- What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: If you're just trying to create a string of a certain length, you can use `var length = new string('a', roomLength);` No loop needed.

Comment: When asking a question make sure to include the exact error message you are getting.  In your case you are likely getting `CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'Lenght'`  This error message gives you most of what you need to know to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;

namespace something
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int roomHeight = 10;
            int roomLength = 10;
            string length = string.Empty;

            for (int i=0; i< roomLength; i++)
            {
                length= string.Join(length, ("a"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Length needs to be assigned before you have it as a parameter in string.Join